# matching Color and collision test of Oval with Graphics string

Tags: java, swing, animation

i'm making a game for my engineering project and i'm facing some problems. There is a part of my code i think should work but its not working. could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong? here is the code from 2 of my classes called AlphabetsColoured and testAlphabets. There is a small part of the code for collision detection of the oval with the alphabets and its not working. please help me.

```
import java.awt.*;     
import java.util.*;

public class AlphabetsColoured 
{

    private Color quescolour, anscolour;
    private int x, y, width, height; 


    public void getQuestion(Graphics g,String alphabet,int x, int y, Color colour)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Font font = new Font("Chalkduster", Font.BOLD+Font.PLAIN, 70);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.setColor(this.quescolour = colour);
        g2.drawString(alphabet, x, y);
    }

    public void getAnswers(Graphics g, String alphabet,int x, int y, Color colour)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Font font1 = new Font("Bloody", Font.BOLD+Font.PLAIN, 30);
        g2.setFont(font1);
        g2.setColor(this.anscolour = colour);
        g2.drawString(alphabet, x, y);

    }

    public Color getQuestionColour()
    {
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.BLACK))
        {
           return Color.BLACK;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.PINK))
        {
           return Color.PINK;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.BLUE))
        {
           return Color.BLUE;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.GREEN))
        {
           return Color.GREEN;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.CYAN))
        {
           return Color.CYAN;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.WHITE))
        {
           return Color.WHITE;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.YELLOW))
        {
           return Color.YELLOW;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.RED))
        {
           return Color.RED;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.ORANGE))
        {
           return Color.ORANGE;
        }
        if (this.quescolour.equals(Color.GRAY))
        {
           return Color.GRAY;
        }
        return Color.MAGENTA;
    }

    public Color getAnswerColour()
    {
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.BLACK))
        {
           return Color.BLACK;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.PINK))
        {
           return Color.PINK;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.BLUE))
        {
           return Color.BLUE;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.GREEN))
        {
           return Color.GREEN;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.CYAN))
        {
           return Color.CYAN;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.WHITE))
        {
           return Color.WHITE;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.YELLOW))
        {
           return Color.YELLOW;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.RED))
        {
           return Color.RED;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.ORANGE))
        {
           return Color.ORANGE;
        }
        if (this.anscolour.equals(Color.GRAY))
        {
           return Color.GRAY;
        }
        return Color.MAGENTA;
    }

    public boolean ColourComparisonTest(AlphabetsColoured alpha1, AlphabetsColoured alpha2)
    {
       if (alpha1.getQuestionColour().equals(alpha2.getAnswerColour()) == true)
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

    public Rectangle getAlphabetBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;

public class testAlphabets extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

    AlphabetsColoured ques = new AlphabetsColoured();
    AlphabetsColoured ans1 = new AlphabetsColoured();
    AlphabetsColoured ans2 = new AlphabetsColoured();
    AlphabetsColoured ans3 = new AlphabetsColoured();
    AlphabetsColoured ans4 = new AlphabetsColoured();
    AlphabetsColoured comparison = new AlphabetsColoured();

    private int y=0, vely=1;           //alphabets velocity
    private int x1=650, y1=650, velx1=5, vely1=5;   //ball velocites

    Timer timer = new Timer(10, this);

    public testAlphabets()
    {
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this); 
        this.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        this.setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        ques.getQuestion(g, "Red", 20, y, Color.cyan);
        ans1.getAnswers(g, "Orange", 400, y+20, Color.ORANGE);
        ans2.getAnswers(g, "Yellow", 600, y-20, Color.PINK);
        ans3.getAnswers(g, "Green", 800, y+50, Color.BLUE);
        ans4.getAnswers(g, "Blue", 1000, y-50, Color.cyan);

        g.fillOval(x1, y1, 50, 50);

        if(comparison.ColourComparisonTest(ques, ans1) == true && Collides(g) == true && (y1==y+20)) 
        {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.drawString("You hit orange" , 500, 500);
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(InterruptedException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
        }
        if(comparison.ColourComparisonTest(ques, ans2) == true && Collides(g) == true && (y1==y-20))
        {
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.drawString("You hit yellow" , 500, 500);
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(InterruptedException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
        }
        if(comparison.ColourComparisonTest(ques, ans3) == true && Collides(g) == true && (y1==y+50))
        {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawString("You hit green" , 500, 500);
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(InterruptedException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
        }
        if(comparison.ColourComparisonTest(ques, ans4) == true && Collides(g) == true && (y1==y-50))
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawString("You hit blue" , 500, 500);
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(InterruptedException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
        }  ///this part of the code is for collision detection of the oval with the 4 colours buts its not working. please help me. im not sure if my Collides and ColourComparisonTest methods are correct. thanks 

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(y < 0)
        {
           vely++;
        }
        if(y > 800)
        {
            vely--;
        }
        if(x1 < 0 || y1 < 0)
        {
           velx1++;
           vely1++;
        }
        if(x1 > 1450 || y1 > 750)
        {
            velx1--;
            vely1--;
        }

        repaint();

        y += vely;

        x1 += velx1;
        y1 += vely1;

    }

    public void up() {
        velx1 = 0;
        vely1 = -4;
    }

    public void down() {
        velx1 = 0;
        vely1 = 4;

    }

    public void left() {
        velx1 = -4;
        vely1 = 0;
    }

    public void right() {
        velx1 = 4;      
        vely1 = 0;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            up();
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            down();
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            left();
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            right();
        }   

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {   
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        velx1 = 0;
        vely1 = 0;
    }

    public boolean Collides(Graphics g)
    {
        if(ans1.getAlphabetBounds().intersects(g.getClipBounds()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(ans2.getAlphabetBounds().intersects(g.getClipBounds()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(ans3.getAlphabetBounds().intersects(g.getClipBounds()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(ans4.getAlphabetBounds().intersects(g.getClipBounds()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(1500, 850);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        new testAlphabets();
        testAlphabets ggg = new testAlphabets();
        f.add(ggg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please tell more -- how is it supposed to work? -- how is it not working?

Comment: One problem is evident: your paintComponent method is missing the `super.paintComponent(g);` call which should be its first line. But otherwise, I'm still awaiting your clarification and question improvement.

Comment: Other issues: you have `Thread.sleep(...)` within your painting method, something that should **never** be done. Let the timer handle all sleeping behaviors. You also have program logic within your painting method, something that should also be avoided. The painting methods should be for painting only.

Comment: Basically this is  what i'm trying to do: 5 colours appear on the screen. the colour alphabet on the left side is the question alphabet and the 4 colour alphabets after the question alphabet are the choices. when the user touches any one of the four alphabets, and the colour of that alphabet matches with the colour of the question alphabet. the score should increase by +2(this is not added to the code yet). so my comparison if statement is not working and im not sure why.

Comment: ***Anyone?* Please have a look